# Getting the result of a method Future<T> flutter

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, future

I have a method

```
Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return user;
}
```

I want to be able to call it in some other module by doing :

```
if (class.getCurrentUser() != null) {
    // Do something
}
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to get the actual value, and not the Future object storing the value. In C++ for instance, I can just do `future.get()`, which will block and return the value to me. Is there an equivalent in flutter? I am new to the language and have searched for hours and cannot seem to find a solution to this exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it seems you actually need 1 `await` only:

```dart
Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
    return _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
}
```

```dart
if (await class.getCurrentUser() != null) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to await for the result in your method call as well like this:

```
FirebaseUser currentUser = await class.getCurrentUser();
if (currentUser != null) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: In that case, is it worth having the await in the original method? Seems a little bit clunky, as I will have to do this every time I call this method.

Comment: @hromer Sadly, that's how futures work in dart. You will need both awaits.

Comment: @dshukertjr see man answer, actually the code does not need to be that verbose.